# iOS push notification badge number over icon is not showing

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have received push notification in my iphone app but badge number is not shown over icon when got notification.when i click the notification to open the app and close it,then badge is shown.my push notification payload format is

```
{
    "aps" : {
        'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'badge' => 1
    },
    'plsID' : '105',

}
```

and my code for showing badge is

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey: @"badge"] intValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that literally what the payload is? If it has those "=>"s it's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem. I tried below code and got it worked

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```